# How to give path of sqljdbc_auth.dll in arguments while running a jar file from cmd?

Tags: java, sql-server, dll, windows-authentication, sqljdbc

Is there a way to give path of "sqljdbc_auth.dll" in command line arguments while running a jar?

Comment: Have you tried anything like `-Djava.library.path="C:\Path To Your\Dll\Folder"`?

Comment: Not tried it yet.

Comment: need to run like this-

Comment: java Djava.library.path="C:\Path" -jar file.jar ?

Comment: worked thank you...